# SVProgressHUD dismiss in viewWillDisappear OK?

Tags: iphone, ios, svprogresshud

Is it OK to call `[SVProgressHUD dismiss]` without ever showing it? The reason I want to do this is because I want the HUD to always disappear when the view disappears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's OK, so long as it doesn't crash LOL.  It should be fine, and it's not like it'll take down the whole app or remove some critical code if it goes wrong anyhow.

Literally, it's just try it and see for now.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can check if the SVProgressHUD is being shown.

so the code in your `viewWillDisappear:` will look like

```
if([SVProgressHUD isVisible]) 
     [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
```